# How to add attribute in magento 2 with custom design?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to add something like this in my product page.
[image]

for that I have created group(electrical, UL and iec) in one attribute set. but I don't know how to add like this.I have created attributes rated voltage, rated current etc.

Comment: check [this](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/) link maybe it will solve your issue

Comment: or you can create one block for above attributes and just call into phtml file, after that call that phtml file as a new custom tab in your product page follow [this](https://webkul.com/blog/display-custom-tab-product-page-magento2/) for example

Comment: I added same thing like this: one attribute like text area, unfortunately you need paste/write all specification with formatting for every single product. Later you can show this in extra tab on product page ( how is different question)